# The largest size of 2-D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

in my C program, when I am taking an array like this

```
int a[100000][100000];
```

I am getting segmentation fault. Now if I am using array of size less than 1000 * 1000 , like this

```
int a[1000][1000];
```

I am not getting any problem.In my program I need to use a 10^5 * 10^5 array. What should I do to fix it .

Comment: Dynamically allocate it with `malloc`. By declaring it statically you use the stack, which has a maximum size that the heap (used in dynamic allocations) does not.

Comment: Oh, you're causing _stack overflow_.

Comment: @devnull I see what you did there! :D

Comment: Allocating a 10GB array may not be the best idea...

Comment: @devnull Stackoverflow without stack? :P

Comment: Do you *have* that much memory in your system? Is it a 64-bit system? Do you declare the variable as a local variable (inside a function) or as a global variable?

Comment: Do you really ***really*** need that many int at any given time?

Comment: No but for some cases,that is required

Comment: You might also want to think about [memory mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), and only work on a portion of the data at a time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ij am using 64-bit system.I declare it as a local variable

Comment: @jahan: you do realize that you're going to use `10000000000*sizeof(int)` bytes of memory with this, right? If you have that much memory to begin with, that's your business. But ask yourself if there isn't a better way

Comment: Oh God! I was not thinking like that.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what should I do if my question is duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically allocate it with `malloc`. By declaring it statically you use the stack, which has a maximum size that the heap (used in dynamic allocations) does not.

```
int *pointer = malloc (sizeof (*pointer) * (100000*100000));
```

Then, to access it, use indices to represent the `x` and `y` coordinates.

Comment: I need to use it as indices of array. How can I do that?

Comment: @jahan: `pointer[0][0]` or `pointer[0]` will give you an int...

Comment: @jahan Have variables for the `x` and `y`. Access with `int valueToUse = *(pointer+(x*100000)+y)`.

Comment: @jahan If you want e.g. `pointer[a][b]` then you can't use the technique in this answer. I'll add another method as answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes I want to have a different answer.

Comment: @jahan Can't add since the question is closed, but pointer to pointer to `int` might be the way to go.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Since this thread is on hold, try a chat room instead. jahan seems to have enough rep for it.

Comment: But what should I do in such cases. I think it is not fair at 
SO. We beginners are not duplicating anything.

Comment: @AntonH how can I start a chat room?

Comment: @jahan You can't, you need at least 100 rep. but Joachim can, and then invite you.