# Getting segmentation fault while using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I asked my problem here [The largest size of 2-D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472913/the-largest-size-of-2-d-array-in-c) and what I got answer there before declaration as duplicate by some people, I modified my code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,n,m,p = 0 ;
    int sum[100000] = {0};

    scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&p);

    /*for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0 ; j < m ; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = j + 1 ;
        }
    }*/
    int **a = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*m); 

       for(i=0; i<n; i++){
           for(j=0; j<m; j++){
            a[i][j] = j + 1 ;

           }
       }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But still I am getting the same segmentation fault.Please help me to fix it and I hope this question will not be declared as duplicate. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're telling `malloc()` the wrong size.

This:

```
int **a = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

should be:

```
int **a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
```

[Don't cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), and use `sizeof` on the type the return pointer points at, i.e. `int *` which probably has a different size than `int` on your system.

Thus, thus:

```
a[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
```

should be:

```
a[i] = malloc(m * sizeof *a[i]);
```

Add code to make sure all `malloc()` succeed, i.e. never return `NULL`, before relying on the pointers being valid. Also make sure the initial `scanf()` returns `3`, and print out the values of `n`, `m` and `p`. Also remove `sum`.

Comment: +1 (Note: also `a[i] = malloc(m * sizeof **a);` or something like that.)

Comment: Can you give me the whole code? I am still not getting the required output.

Comment: int **a = malloc( n * sizeof *a );
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = malloc( m * sizeof **a); It is not working.

       for(i=0; i<n; i++){
           for(j=0; j<m; j++){
            a[i][j] = j + 1 ;
               
           }
       }
 
 }

Comment: I am using here this extra line. I think it is causing the problem.for(i=0; i<n; i++)

Answer (score 0):

`int **a = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` is wrong. What you want here is an array of pointer, so you should do `int **a = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *)*n);` instead.